# 이도 and 도 are both correct or only 도?

Tags: grammar

I am studying the particle 도 which means too or also. In my book if the last syllable ends with consonant 이도 is used and 도 with vowels. But when I look at the internet only 도 is used.
So, 이도 and 도 both are correct or only 도?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was it a name + 이도? Then, that -이 is like "-y" added to a name.

Comment: Please show some examples of what exactly is confusing you

Answer (score 1):

As far as the particle goes, it is always 도 regardless of the preceding syllable.

이도 can happen (as the comment by Kimo suggests) if 도 is used after a person's name.  When we refer to a person with their given name without 씨 (similar to Mr. or Ms.) because of familiarity (i.e. friends) or age (youths and children), we usually add the name suffix 이 if the name ends with a consonant.  So we would say 영진이 (영진 ends with a consonant), for example, whereas we would just say 영수 (it ends with a vowel).  This is a long established custom related to phonetics (ending a name with a vowel is more natural and can connect with certain particles better).

So if we use 도 after someone's name that ends with a consonant, it will become 이도, as in 영진이도.  The 이 is a name suffix and has nothing to do with the particle 도, but it will create the 이도 form you are wondering about.  Perhaps the book was trying to explain this but didn't do a good job of it.

Such an 이도 is relatively rare, since it can only happen with about half of people's given names and in no other cases.